# Fetching release date of an episode using IMDBpy API in python

Tags: python, imdb, imdbpy

I want to fetch the release date of a episode

> e.g GOT S03E04 - 21 Apr. 2013

I have been able to get to the ID of the episode using this API but can't seem to find my way around to release date. I know that this API fetches release year so it must be fetching release date also somewhere. Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well their is a function in the api -

```
ia.get_movie_release_dates(episodeid)
```

This will fetch the release date of that episode in all the countries. Then you can just fetch the country and its release date according to your need.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!